# Where are the 'sudo crontab -e' entries stored?

Tags: backup, cron

I want to backup my extensive crontab -e entries, where are those stored when I access them as user with `sudo crontab -e` ?

Comment: depending on your setup it under /etc/crontab directories, so if you already backup your  /etc it's already in.

Comment: User crontabs are stored in /var/spool/cron.

Comment: ... so a file named `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` in the case of `sudo crontab -e`